# Is there any way to Disable or to Assign null value for updateAt using timestamp in mongodb schema when i am performing insertion?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timestamp, mongoose-schema

when i use timestamp to insert the currenttime to my db both createAt and updateAt will have same time and when i perform update operation then only updateAt value will be changed.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    parkno:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        unique: true
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
    },
    contactno:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    category:String,
    regno:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        unique: true
    },
    charge:String,
    createdAt: String,
    updatedAt: String
 },
{timestamps: true });
const Vechdb = mongoose.model('vechdb',schema);
module.exports = Vechdb
```

I want only the createAt value when i am inserting the data and updateAt value should be null or it should be disabled. And when i am updating the data in db i want both updateAt and createAt value to be saved in db.